# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 error on array of structs

Tags: c++, struct, typedef

running into this odd error when passing a type def of array of structs to a function. My code is below:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


const int MAXRECORDS = 50;
struct Grades                             // declares a structure
{
    char name[NAMESIZE + 1];
};

typedef Grades gradeType[MAXRECORDS];  


void ReadIt( ifstream &i, gradeType gradeRec, int &h);

int main()

{    
     ifstream indata;
     int numRecord;                // number of records read in
     gradeType studentRecord; 

     /* Some stuff */
     ReadIt(indata, studentRecord, numRecord);               

    /* Other Stuff*/
    return 0;
}



void readIt(ifstream &inData, gradeType gradeRec, int &total)

{
    // never make it here, does not compile
}
```

g++ gives the following error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "ReadIt(std::__1::basic_ifstream >&,
>   Grades*, int&)", referenced from:
>         _main in Grades-10db96.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: You know that C++ is a case-senstiive language, right ? `readIt` is not the same as `ReadIt`.

Comment: ugh that was it. face palm. If you make it an answer I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: No problem - comment converted to answer.

Comment: using array typedefs is pretty confusing to the reader

Comment: @Matt McNabb I agree! helping the gf with homework, but would never use this in practice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ is a case-senstiive language. `readIt` is not the same as `ReadIt`.

Comment: @mnunberg's answer will be the next error hit once this part of the problem is fixed.

Comment: `-Wmissing-declarations` might help in GCC. It's saved me a few times when doing something stupid like that

Answer (score 2):

in the *declaration* you're using `gradeRec` whereas in the definition you're using `gradeRec&`. Those are two different symbols.

Comment: That and `ReadIt()`/`readIt()` are two similar but different names.

Comment: sorry, mixed up pasting, its fixed now. Turns out the real error was even stupider than that.